# Jetpack plugin link not working

Tags: linkedin-api, jetpack

I am trying to add a clients linkedin account. The working path is:

https://www.linkedin.com/pub/'username'

the path jetpack is trying to send me to is.

https://www.linkedin.com/in/'username'

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery to replace the href attribute on the broken linkedin  tag. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

just add **..** in the url
ie **https://www.linkedin.com/in/../pub/username**

the **..** will take the user up a diectory to get back to the root url, then append /pub/'username', thus the url entered as:
*https://www.linkedin.com/in/../pub/username*
will be translated into:
*https://www.linkedin.com/pub/username*